# Make new Multidimensional Array in Test class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, chess

I am working on a chess game, but I do not know how can I make a test class and in that test class create a new Array and test methods from ChessClass.

My Chess Table class with a method that makes a random move
    import java.util.Random;

```
public class Chess {

    boolean s [][] = new boolean[8][8];
    Knight kn;
    Random r = new Random();

    public void RandStart(){
        kn = new Knight(r.nextInt(), r.nextInt());
        s [kn.getX()][kn.getY()] = true;
    }


    public void print(){
        for(int i = 0;i < s.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < s[i].length;j++){
                System.out.println(s[i][j]);
            }   
        }
    }



}
```

The only thing I do not know is how to make it work in the test class
I get an error and I can not use the methods from Chess class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Chess m = null;
        m = new Chess[5][5];
        m.RandStart();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `Chess m = null;
        m = new Chess[5][5];` to `Chess m = new Chess();`

Comment: Thank you, It worked.
Write it as an answer

Comment: but seriously if you don't know how to create a new object in Java well, houston YOU have a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main method your are trying to assign a two dimensional `Chess` array to a normal `Chess` object.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Chess m = new Chess();
        m.RandStart();
    }
}
```

Should work to fix your problem.

Also I suggest you change `RandStart()` to `randStart()` good programming practice is all.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

It looks like you want to be able to dynamically set the array size when testing.  You can create two constructors to instantiate your array:

```
boolean s [][] = new boolean[8][8];
Knight kn;
Random r = new Random();

public Chess() {
  s = new boolean[8][8];
}

public Chess(boolean s[][]) {
  this.s = s;
}
```

This way your test can pass in the array in the constructor.  And just a couple of nits, use a better variable name than 's' and tests do not usually use main.  Check out Junit https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to create a new Chess object, but you are far from doing so because `m = new Chess[5][5];` is the syntax for creating a multidimensional array and not an object.
however here is the syntax for creating new Object of the class chess.

```
Chess m = new Chess();
```